# mapping a generator to a list

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a generator function that I want to apply to every item in a list.
Doing a 
`map(foo,var_list)` , gets me a result like :

`[<generator object window at 0x7f20720b1050>, <generator object window at 0x7f20720b10a0>, <generator object window at 0x7f20720b10f0>, <generator object window at 0x7f20720b1140>, <generator object window at 0x7f20720b1190>]`

So I'm thinking I'm going to 'force' it to compute using `map(list(foo),var_list)` but python tells me that's just nonsense.

I can do what I want with a list comprehension, however I can't get my head around how to do that with a map.

A code example is

```
from itertools import islice

def window(seq, n=4):
    if len(seq)<n:
      yield seq
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

result = []
input = 'Hello my name is Steven'
```

And my failing command is `map(window,input.split())`

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name: `map(list, map(foo, my_list))` or `[list(foo(item)) for item in my_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use `lambda`:

```
map(lambda e: list(foo(e)), your_list)
```

This applies `list(foo(e))` for each element `e` in `your_list`.